# What parameter modifying keyword should I use?

Tags: c#, variables, parameters, out, ref

Requirements:

1. Variable doesn't need to be assigned when passing it into the function. (unlike ref)
2. Variable doesn't need to be assigned in the function. (unlike out)

For now, I will call the keyword mykw in the code below.

```
public class MyObj{
    int myInt;
    public void setMyInt(int val){
        myInt = val;
    }
}
public class MyObjContainer{
    private MyObj myObj;
    //this function is the only way the user is allowed to get myObj.
    //it returns whether myObj isn't null
    //this is to disencourage programmers from using myObj without checking if myObj is null
    public bool tryGetMyObj(mykw MyObj tryget){
        if(myObj != null){
            tryget= myObj;
            return true;
        }
        //Micro optimization here: no needless processing time used to assign a value to tryget
        return false;
    }
}
public class MyScript {
    public MyObjContainer[] myObjContainerList;
    public void foo(){
        foreach(MyObjContainer myObjContainer in myObjContainerList){
            MyObj tryget; //Micro optimization here: no needless processing time used to assign a value to tryget
            if(myObjContainer.tryGetMyObj(mykw tryget)){
                tryget.setMyInt(0);
            }
            //else ignore
            //if uses tries accessing tryget.myInt here, I expect C# compiler to be smart enough to find out that tryget isn't assigned and give a compile error
        }
    }
}
```

For the code above, using out or ref in place of mykw gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ref` then you need to initialise the parameter in the caller:

```
public bool tryGetMyObj(ref MyObj tryget) { ... }

MyObj tryget = null;
if(myObjContainer.tryGetMyObj(ref tryget) { ... }
```

If you use `out` then the callee must initialise the value in every path:

```
public bool tryGetMyObj(out MyObj tryget) {
    if(myObj != null){
        tryget= myObj;
        return true;
    }
    tryget = null;
    return false;
}

MyObj tryget;
if(myObjContainer.tryGetMyObj(out tryget)){ ... }
```

Comment: I want a keyword that fits both requirement 1 and requirement 2. I have put the reasons why in the comments in the code snippet I provided.

Comment: @RyanAWE - No such modifier exists so you have to use `ref` or `out` as shown. I wouldn't be sure that they would be slower than the approach you're looking for anyway.

Comment: Is there a way for me to create a parameter modifier that functions as mykw so that I can use it?